# Android RegistrationId push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to get the registrationID from my app. Does the registrationid exist before your app gets sent to the store ? If it doesn't how to I test push notifications ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device registration token that FCM uses to deliver messages for your app to a device is created when an app with the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK is installed on that device. Your app does not need to be in the Play store for that to happen. See the documentation on [accessing the registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) to learn how to get that token in your application code.

The easiest way to test delivery is to [send a notification through the Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#send_a_test_notification_message), in which case you only need the FCM registration token or a topic (that your application code is subscribing to).

To [send a message to the device from (server-side) code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message), you need the FCM token (or topic again), the FCM server key (or OAuth authorization), and the sender ID.